# I am receiving syntax error

Tags: shell, unix

I have below script, but somehow its giving syntax error for line 7 as below. Can you please help me on this.

```
./final.sh
awk: cmd. line:7: "|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3 }
awk: cmd. line:7:                    ^ syntax error

#!/bin/sh
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile="$(date '+/var/tmp/EndpointUsage_%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y.csv')"
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "|-----------------|------------------|";
printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"
}
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "|-------------------|-----------------|"; printf
"|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3 }
END{
print "|------------------|------------------|";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

After Etan Update...But still getting same error now on line 6

```
awk: cmd. line:6: "|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3 }
awk: cmd. line:6:                    ^ syntax error


#!/bin/sh

ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile="$(date '+/var/tmp/EndpointUsage_%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y.csv')"
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "|-----------------|------------------|";
printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"}
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "|-------------------|-----------------|"; printf
"|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3 }
END{
print "|------------------|------------------|";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

Comment: Don't split your line after `printf`.

Comment: Hi Etan, I tried what you suggested but still its same as you can see above

Comment: You misunderstood me. The problem is that you have `printf\n` on the end of the `Ongoing Calls` line. Don't do that. In general your awk script indentation and formatting is fairly terrible and you should really clean it up a bit.

Comment: find the printf just before the string presented in the error message. Put them on the same line. good luck.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your help. Problem is fixed now.